# load SSL CA's from string as opposed to from file

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'd like to store my CAs in a string inside my binary instead of loading it in via SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations, which takes in file paths and folder paths.

However, I can't find a method that lets me take in a string.

Comment: Not a good idea. You want the trusted CAs to be configurable, not hardwired into your code.

Comment: why would this be the case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a documented way to do this. The only way I know of is to roll your own verification, e.g. create a store using X509_STORE_CTX_new, add the trusted CAs with X509_STORE_CTX_trusted_stack, add the certificate with X509_STORE_CTX_set_cert add some other chain certificates and CRLs with similar function and finally call X509_verify_cert on the X509_STORE_CTX.

Comment: Yeah, looking through the 1.0.1 sources, it does not look like its possible. There are some `*_file` functions, but they take a filename. None take a `string` or `byte array` or `BIO`.

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured out how to do it. OpenSSL has a bunch of ways to deal with loading certs, and many of them add the certs to the non-trusted chain. You must use SSL_CTX_get_cert_store and X509_STORE_add_cert in conjunction. These two functions take in X509 pointers, which can be created from a raw c string. Since the documentation is pretty much non-existent for these two functions, so I figured I'd share the code here:

Edit: this is basically Steffen Ulrich's method except using X509_STORE_add_cert.

```cpp
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>

void read_cert_into_ctx(istream &some_stream, SSL_CTX *ctx) {
    // Add a stream of PEM formatted certificate strings to the trusted store
    // of the ctx.
    string line;
    string buffer;
    while(getline(some_stream, line)) {
        buffer.append(line);
        buffer.append("\n");
        if(line == "-----END CERTIFICATE-----") {
            BIO *bio;
            X509 *certificate;
            bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
            BIO_puts(bio, buffer.c_str());
            certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, 0, NULL);
            if(certificate == NULL)
                throw std::runtime_error("could not add certificate to trusted\
                                          CAs");
            X509_STORE* store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(ctx);
            int result = X509_STORE_add_cert(store, certificate);
            BIO_free(bio);
            buffer = "";
        }
    }
}
```